# #1091 error when trying to drop foreign key constraint self-referenced in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a Magento 2 database and when trying to do a migration I run into the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1826 Duplicate foreign key constraint name `MGA7_CAT_CTGR_ENTT_DEC_ATTR_ID_MGA7_EAV_ATTR_ATTR_ID`
```

This error occurs when Magento attempts to create constraints and foreign keys that already exist in that same table.

To solve it I need to drop the duplicate foreign key as a first step. However, when trying to drop it with:

```
ALTER TABLE `mga7_catalog_category_entity_decimal`
DROP FOREIGN KEY `MGA7_CAT_CTGR_ENTT_DEC_ATTR_ID_MGA7_EAV_ATTR_ATTR_ID`;
```

I get error #1091 from MySQL saying it cannot drop it because apparently the constraint does not exist.

But I have been able to verify that the constraint DOES exist with the following query:

```
SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME 
FROM information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
WHERE CONSTRAINT_NAME = 'MGA7_CAT_CTGR_ENTT_DEC_ATTR_ID_MGA7_EAV_ATTR_ATTR_ID';
```

Why does MySQL say the constraint does not exist when it actually shows up? Additionally, the constraint is "self-referencing" the same table:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE  
WHERE REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME IS NOT NULL
AND REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME IS NOT NULL 
AND CONSTRAINT_NAME = 'MGA7_CAT_CTGR_ENTT_DEC_ATTR_ID_MGA7_EAV_ATTR_ATTR_ID';
```

How can I properly drop or temporarily disable this problematic foreign key in order to proceed with the Magento migration?

Any help is greatly appreciated in advance!

---

```
CREATE TABLE `mga7_catalog_category_entity_int` (
  `value_id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Value ID',
  `attribute_id` smallint unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Attribute ID',
  `store_id` smallint unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Store ID',
  `entity_id` int unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Entity ID',
  `value` int DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Value',
  PRIMARY KEY (`value_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `CATALOG_CATEGORY_ENTITY_INT_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID_STORE_ID` (`entity_id`,`attribute_id`,`store_id`),
  KEY `CATALOG_CATEGORY_ENTITY_INT_ENTITY_ID` (`entity_id`),
  KEY `CATALOG_CATEGORY_ENTITY_INT_ATTRIBUTE_ID` (`attribute_id`),
  KEY `CATALOG_CATEGORY_ENTITY_INT_STORE_ID` (`store_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=20092 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3 COMMENT='Catalog Category Integer Attribute Backend Table'
```

Comment: Provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE mga7_catalog_category_entity_decimal;` output.

Comment: Table Create Table mga7_catalog_category_entity_decimal CREATE TABLE `mga7_catalog_category_entity_decimal...

Comment: I do not see `MGA7_CAT_CTGR_ENTT_DEC_ATTR_ID_MGA7_EAV_ATTR_ATTR_ID` in the table structure.. maybe you can? point me on it..

Comment: *the constraint is "self-referencing" the same table* We cannot see the output until you provide it.

Comment: That is the problem say like exist but i cant see

Comment: You refer on the result of your queries to INFORMATION_SCHEMA tables... please explain, why do you persist in hiding them?